# Can the editor be the referee at the same time?

Tags: journals, editors, journal-workflow

According to what I know, the standard procedure of reviewing an article is the editor to skim the article first, then find the referee(s), then the referees review the article, write the report, and the editor decides to accept the article or not.

I am curious, can the editor themselves be the referee at the same time? What are the reasons if such thing happens? Or it never happens?

Comment: Definitely.  In the worst case, I've had an editor pretend to be a referee and ask me to cite his papers.  This is a big name (prolific) professor -- one has to wonder how he became 'big'.

Comment: As an editor who’s been asked to do this, I posted a comment on that earlier thread.